# Пропускаются точки останова

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Здравствуйте.

Ставлю точку останова на методе `Foo1()`, который содержит в себе вызов в цикле `var x=await Foo2()`, на которую тоже ставлю точку останова. При достижении программой точки останова на `Foo2()` нажимаю F10. При этом программа возвращается на точку `Foo1()`, не останавливаясь на строках кода, которые идут после `Foo2()`. Раньше было какое-то сообщение об отсутствующих символах отладки в программе, но сейчас его нет.

В чем может быть проблема и как её решить? Спасибо.

```
internal async static Task Dosmth()
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < ownersCount; i++)
        {
            Foo1(i+1);                
        }           
    }
private async static void Foo1(int id)
    {
        CompanionId[] companions 
            = await Foo2(id);

        for (int i = 0; i < companions.Length;i++ )
        {
            fun();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, но Вы точно уверены, что Foo2() обязательно должен выполнятся. Может же быть такое, что он находится с блоке кода, который просто обходится логикой программы, например, по if.

Comment: Да, Foo2 идёт первой же строкой без предусловий.

Comment: А если остановить на Foo1(), а потом трассировать программу пошагово, что получается?

Comment: Дайте код, посмотрим нормально.

Comment: Прохожу по F11, начиная с Foo1(). Последовательно проходит весь код реализации Foo2(), затем снова останавливается на Foo1().

Comment: Какая версия студии у вас? Не копались ли в настройках или, может, аддоны ставили?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего удивительного - если понимать, как работает await. Когда вы нажимаете F10, происходят две вещи:
1. вызывается Foo2,
2. и сразу же происходит выход из Foo1.

Выполнение Foo1 продолжится после завершения задачи, которую вернула Foo2. Но эта задача выполнится только через некоторое время - а вот новый вызов Foo1 происходит сразу же. Поэтому и срабатывает точка останова.

Если вам надо этот код как-то отладить, попробуйте настроить HitCount на вашей точке останова, чтобы она срабатывала только на первой итерации.

Comment: Может быть ещё проблема в том, что `Foo1` объявлен как `void`, а не `Task`. В результате его вызов никем не `await`'ится.

Comment: Если его объявить как Task - то он от этого автоматически эвейтиться не начнет :)

Comment: Это да, но тогда его можно будет ещё и заэвейтить.

Comment: Но не факт, что так нужно делать. Мне почему-то кажется, что автор хотел сделать вычисления параллельными... впрочем, это в любом случае выходит за рамки вопроса.

Comment: Хм, может быть, так и есть.

Answer (score 1):

Уберите `await` и так попробуйте продебажить. Также попробуйте точку остановка поставить внутри  Foo2().